# Android Library Gradle release JAR

Tags: java, android, jar, gradle, aar

How can I release Jar packaging of `android-library` project?
I've found, classes.jar is located under `build/bundles/release/classes.jar` and I suppose this is correct Jar package (contains `*.class` files).

Is there some official way, to release library as JAR instead of AAR ?

**Edit**
I use Gradle to release Maven artifacts, and I'd like to release JAR along with AAR package.   So JAR with signature, md5, manifest, ...
based on https://chris.banes.me/2013/08/27/pushing-aars-to-maven-central/

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

configurations {
    archives {
        extendsFrom configurations.default
    }
}

def sonatypeRepositoryUrl
if (isReleaseBuild()) {
    println 'RELEASE BUILD'
    sonatypeRepositoryUrl = "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/"
} else {
    println 'DEBUG BUILD'
    sonatypeRepositoryUrl = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
}

if(!hasProperty('nexusPassword')) {
    ext.set('nexusPassword', System.console().readPassword("\n\$ Type in password for Sonatype nexus account " + nexusUsername + ": "))
}

if(!signing.hasProperty('password')) {
    ext.set('signing.password', System.console().readPassword("\n\$ Type in GPG key password: "))
}

afterEvaluate { project ->
    uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

                pom.artifactId = POM_ARTIFACT_ID

                repository(url: sonatypeRepositoryUrl) {
                    authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: nexusPassword)
                }

                pom.project {
                    name POM_NAME
                    packaging POM_PACKAGING
                    description POM_DESCRIPTION
                    url POM_URL

                    scm {
                        url POM_SCM_URL
                        connection POM_SCM_CONNECTION
                        developerConnection POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION
                    }

                    licenses {
                        license {
                            name POM_LICENCE_NAME
                            url POM_LICENCE_URL
                            distribution POM_LICENCE_DIST
                        }
                    }

                    developers {
                        developer {
                            id "loopj"
                            name "James Smith"
                        }
                        developer {
                            id "smarek"
                            name "Marek Sebera"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    signing {
        required { isReleaseBuild() && gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("uploadArchives") }
        sign configurations.archives
    }

    task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
        source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    }

    task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar) {
        classifier = 'javadoc'
        from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
    }

    task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
        classifier = 'sources'
        from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    }

    artifacts {
        archives androidSourcesJar
        archives androidJavadocsJar
    }
}
```

using

```
task androidJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}
```

will package only java files, not compiled and linked against android sdk

Answer (score 94, accepted):

While I haven't tried uploading the artifacts with a deployment to Sonatype (or even a local repo), here's what I managed to come up with [a few weeks ago](https://github.com/square/fest-android/pull/80) when trying to tackle the same problem.

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
  def name = variant.buildType.name
  if (name.equals(com.android.builder.core.BuilderConstants.DEBUG)) {
    return; // Skip debug builds.
  }
  def task = project.tasks.create "jar${name.capitalize()}", Jar
  task.dependsOn variant.javaCompile
  task.from variant.javaCompile.destinationDir
  artifacts.add('archives', task);
}
```

Then run the following:

```
./gradlew jarRelease
```

Comment: I'm afraid, this is correct answer :-) Thanks, I'll post final edit I've made to get it work

Comment: I can also confirm that this works. Note that the generated task does not show up when running **`gradle tasks`**, only with **`gradle tasks --all`**.  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks this does help, but it still doesn't generate the class files for dependencies. I'm trying to make an SDK jar basically that will be a single jar to pass out, but this compile does not include module projects that it is dependent on and does not pull down jars from the dependency section etc.. Do you have any suggestions to accomplish this where it compiles the library projects into the jar as well so I don't have to hand out 4 jars, one for each library project. Then it would be nice to figure out how to include the maven dependency jars too like Gson or Otto.

Comment: This seems to break for me when I add flavors because it tries to create several of the same named tasks without a flavor included. I'm no Groovy guy and cannot figure out how to add the flavor to the task name. I'd appreciate any hints on how to do that.

Comment: I had a small addition to Jake's solution that accounts for any java resources - add `task.dependsOn variant.processJavaResources` and
`task.from variant.processJavaResources.destinationDir` (sorry, couldn't work out how to format this properly)

Comment: Can someone point out how can I use proguard with this configuration? It seems that defining the buildTypes with proguard does not apply.

Comment: @Kevin, I exchanged the `"jar${name.capitalize()}"` part with `"jar${variant.name.capitalize()}"` to make the task account for the flavour name too (the `variant.name` is composed from both buildType name and productFlavor name)

Comment: @SamDozor please follow the link for proguard support http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/05/create-jar-libray-with-gradle-using-aar.html

Comment: @Piklor, I tried adding your lines for getting the resources included but it didn't work. Could you mention the entire task code you used please

Comment: @keno, unfortunately I can't locate the code in question.

Comment: it seems this is not going to package a .png resource into the .jar, is there a way to package an image resource into the jar ?

Comment: @CommonsWare any thoughts on packaging images with gradle into jar?

Comment: @2cupsOfTech: Well, you can't put Android resources into a JAR, only an AAR. You're welcome to play around with classic Java resources in the JAR, but I have not tried it, and it's not commonly done.

Comment: @CommonsWare this script doesn't produce an obfuscated jar I believe, is that possible to do?

Comment: @2cupsOfTech: Beats me

Comment: @jake-wharton how to build an obfuscated jar using your script?

Comment: @2cupsOfTech to generate an obfuscated jar I used the alternative method of copying the Jar that is already generated by the library build in /build/intermediates/bundles/release (as mentioned by Jani). I guess Jani should an alternative answer here. It works for both obfuscated and non obfuscated libraries and seems simpler to me.

Comment: @Jani you should post an answer here with your alternative method. It would help others as it also handles obfuscated cases.

Comment: @Olinasc I ended up writing a small shell script to convert a jar to an obfuscated jar using proguard

Comment: @2cupsOfTech I understand. This seems though as more work than is needed. I will post the alternative answer here if Jani does not reply.

Comment: @Olinasc its a 1 line script, look into command: 'java -jar -outjars -injars', my script is not general otherwise I would post, this link could be helpful: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html

Comment: @2cupsOfTech I no longer have access to the build.gradle file that I used this alternative method. Please post the answer. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to generate a jar from a library project through gradle is as follows:

In your library's build.gradle:

```
def jarName = 'someJarName.jar'

task clearJar(type: Delete) {
    delete "${project.buildDir}/libs/" + jarName
}

task makeJar(type: Copy) {
    from("${project.buildDir}/intermediates/bundles/release/")
    into("${project.buildDir}/libs/")
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar', jarName)
}

makeJar.dependsOn(clearJar, build)
```

What we are doing here is just copying the classes.jar generated by the Android Gradle plugin. Be sure to look into your build directory for this file and see if its contents are in the way you want.

Then run the `makeJar` task and the resulting jar will be in library/build/libs/`${jarName}`.jar

The will have the class files according to your configuration for release. If you are obfuscating it, then the files in the jar will be obfuscated.

Answer (score 0):

Just because the previous answers were not fitting my needs, I share my tricky version to generate a jar with the project classes and the aar/jar dependencies.

```
// A tricky jar operation, we want to generate a jar files that contains only the required classes used.
// Dependencies are in jar and aar, so we need to open the aar to extract the classes and put all at the same level
// (aar is a zip that contains classes.jar, the latter is a zip that contains .class files)
task jar(type: Jar) {
    from {
        List<File> allFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        configurations.compile.collect {
            for (File f : zipTree(it).getFiles()) {
                if (f.getName().equals("classes.jar")) {
                    allFiles.addAll(zipTree(f).getAt("asFileTrees").get(0).getDir())
                }
            }
        }
        allFiles.add(new File('build/intermediates/classes/release'))
        allFiles // To return the result inside a lambda
    }
    archiveName( project.ext.appName + '.jar' )
}
```

This does NOT manage the build types / flavours but can be adapted (it's just ok to build on build-type release without flavour).

If ever you've a smarter or more elegant solution, please share!