# Transitive dependencies not resolved for aar library using gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-library, aar

I have investigated a while and probably saw most popular answers here related to **aar** and **transitive dependencies** but somehow it is still not clear for me how to make this working.

So:

I have android library with given gradle config:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
apply plugin: 'android-maven'

version = "1.0.0"
group = "com.somepackage"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.0'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://www.bugsense.com/gradle/' }
}

dependencies {
    provided 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    provided 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.bugsense.trace:bugsense:3.6'
    compile 'commons-net:commons-net:3.3'
}
```

Then I am deploying it to local maven repo with `gradle install`. POM file of the deployed library looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sprezzat</groupId>
  <artifactId>app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>aar</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.bugsense.trace</groupId>
      <artifactId>bugsense</artifactId>
      <version>3.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
      <version>3.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And finally gradle config of my android application using above library as a dependency:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.somepackage:LIBRARY_NAME:1.0.0@aar'
}
```

And after deploying application on phone I am getting `NoClassDefFoundError` for classes belonging to compile dependencies of my android library.

Inspecting my android application dependencies using `gradle dependencies`:

```
apk - Classpath packaged with the compiled main classes.
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:+ -> 4.3.23
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1 -> 19.1.0
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+ -> 19.1.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0
\--- com.somepackage:LIBRARY_NAME:1.0.0
```

According to above tree, all transitive dependencies are not detected. Where is the problem and how should it be done correctly?

Comment: Have you examined the output of running **`gradle dependencies`** for your app?

Comment: And are you really sure that you want the `provided` keyword there? According to Xav, [such dependencies are not packaged in the APK](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/adt-dev/WIjtHjgoGwA/h1gS9J5xLUAJ), and I would think that you would want those to be packaged in the APK.

Comment: @CommonsWare `gradle dependencies` for my android lib: default - Configuration for default artifacts.
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
+--- com.bugsense.trace:bugsense:3.6
\--- commons-net:commons-net:3.3

Comment: I am not aware that local AAR files like that work -- I think they need to go into a local Maven repository and be referenced that way. But I really was referring to running **`gradle dependencies`** for the *app*, not for a library that somebody decided to name "app".

Comment: @CommonsWare please see updated question. I have installed library to local maven repo but this does not help.

Comment: `@aar` means "just the aar artifact, and no dependencies".

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser so what would be the alternative? Bundle all dependencies in separate jar and provide them together with aar?

Comment: I'd expect that omitting `@aar` would solve the problem.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser but my library provides resources as well. How to solve this issue?

Comment: I am having the same issue.  Never used @aar in compile line. When I build my final APK I pull aar from maven repo, but none of its deps are pulled into the final project, causes noclassdef errors.

Comment: where should i place pom file in aar added app

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I have solved my problem by setting `transitive` attribute for my aar dependency:

```
compile ('com.somepackage:LIBRARY_NAME:1.0.0@aar'){
    transitive=true
}
```

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Omitting the `@aar` causes Gradle to attempt to grab the artifact as a .jar file. This kills the build.

Comment: It did not worked for me. I have the exact problem. I have 2 libraries and one of them is using the other. `compile project(':LeafPeripheralsContract') { transitive=true }` did not work. It complained about transitive. And I created an `aar` and tried to add transitive to it. It did not complain but it did not include it in the other aar package as well.

Comment: Did not work for me either.  I have a classifier in the dependency as well.  Wondering if that is the problem. Using Android Studio RC1 with gradle build tools 0.14.4.

Comment: Yup, if you are using classifiers, doesn't seem like transitive deps work.  Look here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=80989

Comment: if you have both .jar and .aar artifacts, this is the only solution to use the @aar and include transitives.

Comment: where should i place pom file in android application

Comment: In case you are using flavors for your aar you need to workaround this issue as well:
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1487

Comment: can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/77935207/8926845

Answer (score 23):

you should not use "@aar", if use "@" is become "[Artifact only notation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#ssub:artifact_dependencies)", if you want to use "@" and want have dependence transitive, you should add "transitive=true"

Comment: This answer is helpful. There was a typo in my previous comment and I deleted that one. Thanks for your answer, have a good day :).

Answer (score 14):

Try this if you are using aar locally:

```
compile(project(:your-library-name)) {
    transitive=true
}
```

Comment: Hi, its not working for me. I have created one library project which internally uses volley library. I have included aar file created using library project in my application. I am getting "Error:(8, 26) error: package com.android.volley does not exist" error. In my library project, I have included volley using     compile(project(':volley')){
        transitive = true
    }

Comment: Hey Manish, Facing the same issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: I'm stuck with the same problem

Comment: Are you including the aar as flatDir? If so, I would refer you to the following comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698160/can-an-aar-include-transitive-dependencies#comment68753630_25730092

Comment: can you please help in this https://stackoverflow.com/q/77935207/8926845

Answer (score 10):

I was having a similar problem and felt I could share the steps of solving the problem.

The basic idea of not being able to use the transitive dependencies while you are publishing your own `aar` is actually not having the `.pom` file generated with the expected transitive dependencies.

I was using `'maven-publish'` plugin for my android `aar` dependency to publish it in my own private maven repository. The transitive dependencies were not resolved when my other projects were adding my `aar` dependency in their `build.gradle`. Hence here what I did to modify the `.pom` file while publishing my `aar`.

An important thing to note here that, the dependencies which you want to have the transitive behavior should be imported using the `api` in your library project's `build.gradle` file like the following.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    api 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    api "com.google.code.gson:gson:$globalGsonVersion"
}
```

Now as I said earlier, I was using `maven-publish` plugin to publish the `aar` dependency and hence my publishing task in the gradle looks like the following.

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenAar(MavenPublication) {
            from components.android
        }

        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            pom.withXml {
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                // Iterate over the api dependencies (we don't want the test ones), adding a <dependency> node for each
                configurations.api.allDependencies.each {
                    def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            // Your repository information goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Hence, I used another `mavenJava` task to publish the `.pom` file in my private maven repo so that when the `aar` file is added as a dependency to some other module, it gets the `.pom` information and download the transitive dependency.

To complete the answer, this is how you should add the dependency in the `build.gradle` file for your own published `aar` to me imported.

```
api('com.example.masudias:my_lib:1.0.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Not sure why adding the transitive dependencies to the POM isn't default behaviour though.

Comment: Nice one! 
Just to add a point here. 
When the dependencies are added as `api`, the scope of the dependency within the pom file is `compile`. But if the dependencies are added as `implementation`, the scope becomes `runtime` in the pom file.

Comment: Thank you for these addition @NikhilKumar. Appreciate it!

Comment: `An important thing to note here that, the dependencies which you want to have the transitive behavior should be imported using the api in your library project's build.gradle file like the following.` OMG, thank you.

Comment: Спасибо! Мне тоже помог ваш рецепт.

Answer (score 7):

**Transitive dependency**

`transitive` means that the consumer(e.g. app) includes a producer and all producer's dependencies(e.g. libraries). It increase build time and can create some issues with dependency versions

By default, Gradle dependency has `transitive = true`

```
api ('com.package:library:0.0.1')
//the same
api ('com.package:library:0.0.1') {
    transitive = true
}
```

When you use `@artifact notation` it has `transitive = false`

```
api ('com.package:library:0.0.1@aar')
//the same
api ('com.package:library:0.0.1@aar') {
    transitive = false
}
```

Comment: can you please help in this https://stackoverflow.com/q/77935207/8926845

Answer (score 0):

For me complete publishing solution looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'

group = GROUP
version = VERSION

// you could move it to env variable or property
def publishFlavorless = true
def firstTask = null

android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->

    if (variant.name.toLowerCase().contains("debug")) {
        // Workaround for https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1487
        if (publishFlavorless && firstTask == null) {
            def bundleTask = tasks["bundle${variant.name.capitalize()}Aar"]
            firstTask = bundleTask
            artifacts {
                archives(firstTask.archivePath) {
                    builtBy firstTask
                    name = project.name
                }
            }
        }
        return
    }

    def bundleTask = tasks["bundle${variant.name.capitalize()}Aar"]

    artifacts {
        archives(bundleTask.archivePath) {
            classifier variant.flavorName
            builtBy bundleTask
            name = project.name
        }
    }
}

install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        // This generates POM.xml with proper parameters
        pom.project {
            name POM_NAME
            artifactId POM_ARTIFACT_ID
            // For aar it is equal to 'aar' with jar transitive dependencies won't work
            packaging POM_PACKAGING
            description POM_DESCRIPTION
        }
    }
}
```

The `transitive = true` block is required as well ...

Answer (score 0):

AAR file doesn't contain transitive dependencies. So even if use **api** instead of **implementation** it wont work.

In our team we had developed a library to use in our applications and we wanted it to be for internal use only. Earlier we used to include whole module that seems to work. Later we decided to move to aar file but we were also facing same issue of **classpath not found**. After some research we came to know that we can also use local maven repo. We decided to use that.

Here is step by step process

**Publishing repo**

1.In your Library's root build.gradle file you need to include

```
id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' version '2.0' apply false
```

2.In you library's module level build.gradle file you need to add

a) In plugins

```
id 'maven-publish'
```

b) At bottom of gradle file add

```
publishing {
    publications {
        release(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'com.demo.android'
            artifactId = 'qrcodescanner'
            version = '1.0.0'

            afterEvaluate {
                from components.release
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "qrcodescanner"
            url = "${project.buildDir}/repo"

        }
    }
}
```

3.Depends on the name you have given a gradle tasks will be generated you can check using **gradlew tasks** or by using gradle window at top right corner in android studio, Our was

```
publishReleasePublicationToQrcodescannerRepository
```

4.Run it and repo will be generated in given path

```
gradlew publishReleasePublicationToQrcodescannerRepository
```

5. Final step you need to publish it to maven local using

   `gradlew publishToMavenLocal`

if it doesn't work you can try gradlew clean and gradlew build before executing it.

**Using local repo**

1.You need to add **mavenLocal()** in root level build.gradle file of your project you wanted to use it in like this before other central repos

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

2. Now you need to include your dependency in the project like we do with other dependencies as well

`implementation 'com.demo.android:qrcodescanner:1.0.0'`
keep in mind format should **groupdId:artifactId:version**

That's it.

References :

[Publish Library](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish-library)

[Local Maven](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html)

Answer (score -2):

Simply adding @aar at the end of the dependency is what worked for me.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.videolan.vlc:libvlc:3.0.13@aar'
}
```