# How do I ship an Android Library (aar) with remote dependencies (gradle)?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, aar

I am trying to build an aar file with gradle that has remote dependencies. An example build script is below. As you can see I have two dependencies. The problem I'm having is when I do a release, the aar file does not contain the remote dependencies, so when I include the aar file in other projects I get NoClassDefFound errors.

I found that if I copy the jar from my local maven repo to a libs folder in my project, then the jar does get included in the release aar. How do I include the remote dependencies in the aar file? I've also read elsewhere that it's bad practice to ship dependencies like this, so if there's a better way to do what I'm trying to do I'm all for it.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

android {
... omitted for brevity
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.somepackage:someartifact:1.0'
    compile 'com.anotherpackage:artifact:2.0'
}
```

Comment: Hi @fxfilmxf, any proceedings here? Best

Comment: any progress ? i am looking around fro solution but cant find any .. :/

Answer (score 7):

try using the `transitive` attribute:

```
compile ('group_id:artifact_id:version_name@aar'){
    transitive = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check this link:

[Transitive dependencies not resolved for aar library using gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795455/transitive-dependencies-not-resolved-for-aar-library-using-gradle)

you have to create a POM file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sprezzat</groupId>
  <artifactId>app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>aar</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.bugsense.trace</groupId>
      <artifactId>bugsense</artifactId>
      <version>3.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

and deploy it on maven.

After that, you can define it in your android application build.gradle config like this:

```
compile ('com.somepackage:LIBRARY_NAME:1.0.0@aar'){
    transitive=true
}
```