# is it possible to generate an Android library AAR archive with Gradle, automatically fulfilled with maven JARs dependecies?

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, aar

I would like to find out the best way in order to generate with Gradle an Android Library AAR archive containing all the dependencies resolved by maven, thus the application doesn't have to include those dependencies, just import the AAR and everything is configured by the android library.

The jars should be placed by the Gradle task in the AAR libs/ dir.

I was doing this, before the new AAR system, with a JAR containing multiple source sets, just because it was not possible to assemble a binary android library.

Comment: "containing all the dependencies resolved by maven" -- the POM for an AAR should specify dependencies, and then Gradle or Maven can resolve those dependencies. However, the AAR itself should not bundle those dependencies, as that breaks other AARs and libraries that have their own dependencies on the same stuff (e.g., `support-v13`).

Comment: but if I have my local Artifactory and those jar are artifacts, it won't affect other developers, it would be just a useful way in order to include them into a binary android library. I wonder how to release an android binary library containing other java artifacts. I've found out in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075356/how-do-i-ship-an-android-library-aar-with-remote-dependencies-gradle?rq=1) that this could be possible with other AARs with `transitive = true` but I wonder if possible with JARs