# Create aar file in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, aar

I'd like to create an aar file for my library in Android Studio, i would've gone with a jar option but my library has resources.

Any idea how to create an aar file from a library?

Comment: This worked for me: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library

Answer (score 287, accepted):

If your library is set up as an Android library (i.e. it uses the `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` statement in its build.gradle file), it will output an .aar when it's built. It will show up in the **build/outputs/aar/** directory in your module's directory.

You can choose the "Android Library" type in File > New Module to create a new Android Library.

If you are still not seeing your `aar` file, select `Build > Rebuild Project`.

Comment: I know this is an old topic, but is there any way to "version" this?  While it's pretty straightforward to get the .aar created, is there any way to apply a version number to it?  We want to create a distributable library at our company to put in Artifactory and would need versioning.

Comment: The versioning is really external to the AAR itself. You would typically set up a Maven pom file that has version info.

Comment: Or you can create a gradle task that copies the AAR file from the outputs directory and adds a version to it.

Comment: I have aar file in the libs folder of the library so it is not included in the build/outputs/aar/ directly

Comment: aar file appeared in app/build/outputs/aar/ and not in the /build/ folder on the project level! in case you don't find it...

Comment: Note that to generate my `aar`, I had to do a `Build > Rebuild Project` in Android Studio. Simply running, debugging, or Building APK did not generate the `aar` for me.

Comment: @AdamJohns the quicker way being `./gradlew moduleName:assembleRelease` in the terminal tab

Answer (score 199):

## Retrieve exported .aar file from local builds

If you have a module defined as an android library project you'll get .aar files for all build flavors (debug and release by default) in the `build/outputs/aar/` directory of that project.

```
your-library-project
    |- build
        |- outputs
            |- aar
                |- appframework-debug.aar
                 - appframework-release.aar
```

If these files don't exist start a build with

```
gradlew assemble
```

for macOS users

```
./gradlew assemble
```

## Library project details

A library project has a `build.gradle` file containing `apply plugin: com.android.library`. For reference of this library packaged as an `.aar` file you'll have to define some properties like package and version.

Example `build.gradle` file for library (this example includes obfuscation in release):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

## Reference .aar file in your project

In your app project you can drop this `.aar` file in the `libs` folder and update the `build.gradle` file to reference this library using the below example:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs' //this way we can find the .aar file in libs folder
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.0"

    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 4
        versionName "0.4.0"

        applicationId "yourdomain.yourpackage"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'be.hcpl.android.appframework:appframework:0.1.0@aar'
}
```

Alternative options for referencing local dependency files in gradle can be found at: http://kevinpelgrims.com/blog/2014/05/18/reference-a-local-aar-in-your-android-project

## Sharing dependencies using maven

If you need to share these `.aar` files within your organization check out maven. A nice write up on this topic can be found at: https://web.archive.org/web/20141002122437/http://blog.glassdiary.com/post/67134169807/how-to-share-android-archive-library-aar-across

## About the .aar file format

An aar file is just a `.zip` with an alternative extension and specific content. For details check [this link about the aar format](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format).

Comment: Wonderful and detailed answer. +1 for `gradlew assemble` - that solved the problem I was having.

Comment: @hcpl How to convert my android project into .aar file

Comment: @NaveedAhmad did you try ./gradlew

Comment: @NaveedAhmad then you're probably executing from the wrong location or your gradle config is different. You could try "locate gradlew" but really if you're having trouble finding and executing gradlew then this brief answer won't help you

Comment: For posterity: `gradlew` is a script in the **project toplevel directory**.

Answer (score 14):

just like user hcpl said but if you want to not worry about the version of the library you can do this:

```
dependencies {
    compile(name:'mylibrary', ext:'aar')
}
```

as its kind of annoying to have to update the version everytime. Also it makes the not worrying about the name space easier this way.

Answer (score 13):

**To create AAR**

while creating follow below steps.

`File->New->New Module->Android Library and create`.

**To generate AAR**

Go to gradle at top right pane in android studio follow below steps.

`Gradle->Drop down library name -> tasks-> build-> assemble or assemble release`

AAR will be generated in **build/outputs/aar/**

But if we want AAR to get generated in specific folder in project directory with name you want, modify your app level `build.gradle` like below

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER") as Integer ?: 1
    versionName "0.0.${versionCode}"


    libraryVariants.all { variant ->

        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            outputFileName = "/../../../../release/" + ("your_recommended_name.aar")
        }
    }
}
```

Now it will create folder with name "release" in project directory which will be having AAR.

**Updated Answer**

In Latest releases specific path is not supported.Please add below code in library's build.gradle and rebuild project.After Rebuilding "**aar**",change project structure from Android to Project->navigate to your l**ibrary->build->outputs->aar**

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion ..
    targetSdkVersion ..
    versionCode ...
    versionName "1"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-rules.pro'
}

libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
    outputFileName = "${archivesBaseName}_${variant.name}_${defaultConfig.versionName}.aar"
}
```

}}

To import "**aar**" into project,check below link.

[How to manually include external aar package using Gradle for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst/64819440#64819440)

Answer (score 5):

After following the first and second steps mentioned in the [hcpl's answer in the same thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27565045/3811068), we added **, '*.aar'], dir: 'libs'** in the our-android-app-project-based-on-gradle/app/build.gradle file as shown below:

```
...

dependencies {
       implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')

...
```

Our gradle version is com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1

Answer (score 3):

**Build ---> Build bundle/apk**

.aar file will be generated in **build/outputs/aar** folder.

Answer (score 2):

btw @aar doesn't have transitive dependency. you need a parameter to turn it on:
[Transitive dependencies not resolved for aar library using gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795455/transitive-dependencies-not-resolved-for-aar-library-using-gradle)

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49663101/9640177

> `implementation files('libs/aar-file.aar')`

**Edit**
I had one more complication - I had set minifyEnabled true for the library module.

Answer (score 0):

[[JAR vs AAR]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65789668/4770877)

`.jar` is generated by `apply plugin: 'java-library'`

`.aar` is generated by `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`

```
File -> New -> New Module... -> Android Library
```

Comment: Ok but how to locate the .aar after we create a new module android library?

Answer (score 0):

If you have [correctly set up](https://github.com/fcat97/zeroLevel/blob/d5ec76f9aaca889c669454d0918f9982ec61ca38/Publish%20Library%20To%20Jitpack.md) for publishing, then you can just run this command to generate `aar` files.

```
 ./gradlew publishReleasePublicationToMavenLocal
```

This will generate a `aar` file inside `<module-dir>/build/output/aar` directory.

Now you can use this library in other local projects also. Add this in the project `gradle` in which you want to use this `aar` module

```
implementation fileTree(dir: '<location-to-library>/build/outputs/aar/', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'], exclude: [])
```