# Creating *.aar library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, aar

Hi I'm a new in Android development and using Android studio. I need to create *.aar lib. I created New Android library project (empty for now). How to generate *.aar file from it? Can you explain by steps? Has read a lot of topics but still unsuccessful. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: do you have build/outputs folder?

Comment: How to check or how to configure it? Sorry but I'm new in it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create aar file in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309950/create-aar-file-in-android-studio)

Comment: What to check? Check if you have folder in your project tree?

Comment: @MihaiC I read it but didn't understand...

Comment: @pskink I added image of my tree (so I think I don't)

Comment: Is there any aar file in the build folder?

Comment: @pskink nope. It's clean.

Comment: So build your project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65689/discussion-between-simha-and-pskink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @pskink, found out, need to build it like: "gradlew assemble" from the root of project.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what has worked for me.

1. on the command line go to the root directory of the project
2. ensure that your JAVA_HOME environment variable points to the version of the java sdk you are going to use.  On a Mac via the bash shell that would look something like this:

   export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home'

(click [here to find out how to find your Java Home](https://www.google.com/search?q=find%20java_home%20in%20java&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8))

3. To clean type ./gradlew clean
4. To build the library type ./gradlew aR (This may take a while)

You should now find the .aar file in mymodulename/build/outputs/aar

Thanks to [geekgarage](http://geekgarage.dad3zero.net/create-a-standalone-library-with-android-studio/) for clarification.