# How to compile zxing to aar?

Tags: java, android, maven, zxing, aar

I am green with maven, how to compile aar library from zxing project?
I tried use axis2 maven plugin, but i get error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project android: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.google.zxing:android:jar:4.7.0: The
>   following artifacts could not be resolved:
>   com.google.zxing:core:jar:3.1.1-SNAPSHOT,
>   com.google.zxing:android-core:jar:3.1.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find
>   artifact com.google.zxing:core:jar:3.1.1-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Do you mean an .apk? what's an aar?

Comment: @SeanOwen: Android Archive. The format for android libraries. It includes the compiled java source and the resources. see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format

Comment: did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309950/create-aar-file-in-android-studio ?

Comment: `android/` isn't a library and shouldn't be treated as one, so you won't be able to create an .aar for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you're trying to do, the error means what it says. There is no 3.1.1-SNAPSHOT artifact until you create and install one locally. You can do that with `mvn -DskipTests install` at the top level. See also https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Getting-Started-Developing