# How to share SDK without src folder

Tags: android, sdk

I am working on SDK and it is almost completed. I want to share SDK with clients. Now I am facing a problem that I have to share SDK with others clients with src folder. When I am deleting src folder from my SDK then, in a project where clients are integrating my SDK, there it is giving an error that my SDK classes are not available.

How to do in such a way so that I don't need to share src folder of my SDK just like Appcompat library do. They only share res and their jar files.

Comment: please refer to this question on how to create a library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309950/create-aar-file-in-android-studio

Comment: @Budius I can not create aar file because I need to share res folder as well. How to do with this aar file ? and how it can be dup of that ?

Comment: Even though you asked in a very different way. That is exactly what you need. The AAR file contains all the resource folders inside it and everything else that an Android library might need. That's the reason why AAR were created, and that's how the `AppCompat` does it.

Comment: @Budius Ok thanks but I am using ADT and my client is also using ADT. will it work on that ? if so how to create aar file in adt