# Where does an Android Library compile to?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-library

This is probably a stupid question, but I've tried searching both on StackOverflow and on my file system, and I can't find it.

I have an Android Library project. When I compile the project, where does the compiled library go? Or is there something special I need to do to get the library?

Comment: What are you using to compile?

Comment: I'm just doing a "Sync Project with Gradle Files" and then build -> make project.

Comment: Could you please be elaborate and what are the steps you did. What do you mean by compiled library?

Comment: @TheCuriousDev Well it's a library, so I'm supposed to get some kind of a compiled file similar to a jar which can be added as a dependency to other projects, yes?

With regard to elaborating on the steps I took, my comment above is all I did - those are two buttons in Android Studio, and I clicked them in that order.

Comment: Have you tired [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309950/create-aar-file-in-android-studio). Its pretty straight forward if you have setup your project as Library project.Hope that link would help you.

Answer (score 0):

An *Android Library* compiles to an `aar` file.

For libraries built with *gradle*, you can find the file in the `build/outputs/aar` directory of your project