# How to make java class that it contains some Persian entries to jar file

Tags: java, android

I have just a class I want to become the JAR file And because it contains some Persian entries After converting to a JAR file is written in Persian Is troubled And for this reason Farsi entries must be defined in file string

I have an array which was defined in string file and I'm going to put it in a static variable as follows

```
private static String[] array1 =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arrayName);
```

Because my class is non-activity `getResource` method is not recognized. On the other hand, even if be my class of n-type activity not be done the array poured in a static variable.

Comment: I cant get your exact problem. Please explain it with proper way.

Comment: If you create JAR library for android project then better to create `AAR` file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309950/create-aar-file-in-android-studio