# Android Studio Library Module to AAR file for Dynamic Loading

Tags: android-studio, dex

I have an Android Studio project that has two modules:

1. app (dependencies on common.jar  and ext)
2. ext (dependecies on common.jar)

common.jar has most of the model logic of my app.

Right now the app uses reflection to find and instantiate the extension service. Since the class is in the APK the nornal classloaded finds it.

Now I want to sever the app's dependency on the ext module and use DexClassLoader to find the service class from an AAR file.

I have used java and the AndroidSDK dx tool to create a simple JAR file to verify I have the dynamic loading working ... I can find, instantiate, and execute methods from the test JAR file.

I just can't figure out how to make Android Studio generate the AAR file for my library module.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer burried in:

[Create aar file in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309950/create-aar-file-in-android-studio)

I saw this before ... but missed the key missing information ...

Using Gradle menu ... I have never used or noticed this before.