# Cannot include transitive dependencies from AAR

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

So, I have a project which is split into library and application part; library is expected to be released to wide audience, thus I need to make it `.aar` (or, rather, `.aar` + `.pom`).

In `library/build.gradle`.. nothing significant.

In `app/build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
 flatDir {
  dirs "/tmp/testlibdir/"
 }
}
...
apply plugin: 'android'
compile ('foo.bar:baz-lib:0.0.1@aar') { transitive=true }
```

POM is available as `/tmp/testlibdir/baz-lib-0.0.1.pom`, `/tmp/testlibdir/pom.xml`, and .aar is `/tmp/testlibdir/baz-lib-0.0.1.aar`.

Gradle won't load any dependencies from that POM, so I get a lot of `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:` in runtime.

What's wrong with it?

I've repeated the path done in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698160/can-an-aar-include-transitive-dependencies?), however it won't work.

---

Also tried to use

```
android {
    publishNonDefault true
}
```

in `library/build.gradle`, no effect.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I am in the same situation as you were at that point. Can you share your solution?