# How to specify dependencies in aar library?

Tags: dependencies, android-gradle-plugin, pom.xml, aar

I created an Android library (called *MyLib*) which depends on other library available on maven repo (like *gson*, *retrofit*, etc.).

```
MyLib
 |
 |-- Retrofit
 |-- Gson
 |-- ...
```

MyLib is packaged to an `aar` file.

The goal is to publish an aar library which can be included into an Android app (called *MyApp*) without specifying a second time the dependencies that *MyLib* uses.

```
MyApp
 |
 |-- MyLib
 |    |-- Retrofit
 |    |-- gson
 |    |-- ...
```

This is my *build.gradle* file for *MyLib*

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
}
```

Now, if I want to build and run *MyApp* without dependency issue, I had to use the following build.gradle for *MyApp* (if I don't specify *retrofit* and *gson* as deps, a runtime exception is thrown because the deps are not available).

```
dependencies {
    compile('MyLib@aar')

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
}
```

I don't want to specify in *MyApp* the dependencies that are used inside *MyLib*, How should I write my build.gradle files?

Thansk in advance

Comment: If MyLib is local, you should use compile project(':MyLib')

Comment: Yes, MyLib is local but packaged into an aar. MyLib and MyApp are not in the same project. It is two different project.

Comment: You can always refer to another folder outside the projetc

Comment: Refer to a project yes, but how it is possible to perform "compile projet('MyLib@aar')"?

Answer (score 7):

When publishing an `aar` to a maven repository (local or remote) and including it using `compile (...@aar)` transitive dependencies are turned off.

To enable transitive dependencies for an `aar` library:

```
compile ('com.mylib:mylib:1.0.0@aar'){
       transitive=true
}
```

You can read more about this here:

[Can an AAR include transitive dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698160/can-an-aar-include-transitive-dependencies)

This works with `aar` libraries that are published to a remote or local maven repository, In your case it sounds like the library will not be published to even a local maven repository. I can't find any definitive information as to if it will work in your circumstances, but you should give it a shot.

Comment: I'm now able to generate a pom-default.xml file containing deps when building the aar library to publish to local repo (using maven and maven-publish gradle plugins). But this pom file is not included inside the aar archive (it is only visible in the build folder but not included inside the final archive). How can I embedded it inside the aar archive?

Comment: @BrentM, is the same thing mentioned in the question possible, if the aar file is present in libs directory of Android applicaiton:
compile(name:'library_name', ext:'aar')
I understand that you did not find any definitive information for this use-case. But, is there any update which you have regarding this? Thanks!