# How to specify dependencies in library(sdk) which has multiple modules

Tags: android, dependencies, build.gradle

I have a Library project which has multiple modules, so that i centralised its dependencies in project level *build.gradle* like below

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    minSdkVersion = 9
    targetSdkVersion = 24
    buildToolsVersion = '23.0.3'
    junit = 'junit:junit:4.12'
    mockito = 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    testRunner = 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    appcompat = 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.0'
    retrofit2 = 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    gsonConverter = 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    httpLogInterceptor = 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    design = 'com.android.support:design:24.1.0'
    cardview = 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    universalImageLoader = 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
}
```

and i used it in modules as

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':module1')
    compile rootProject.appcompat
    compile rootProject.retrofit2
    compile rootProject.gsonConverter
    compile rootProject.httpLogInterceptor
    compile rootProject.design
    compile rootProject.cardview
    compile rootProject.universalImageLoader
    testCompile rootProject.junit
    testCompile rootProject.mockito
    androidTestCompile rootProject.junit
    androidTestCompile rootProject.testRunner
}
```

in my sample app (another module in same project), i included the library module as `compile project(':module2')` & it works fine but now i published the sdk in jcenter & if i use it in a new app, the dependencies i mentioned in the library are not resolving.

i tried including the dependency like

```
compile ('com.github.xxx:module2:1.0.0@aar') {
    transitive=true
}
```

and

```
compile 'com.github.xxx:module2:1.0.0'
```

and

```
compile ('com.github.xxx:module2:1.0.0') {
    transitive=true
}
```

i have tried

[How to specify dependencies in aar library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30749728/how-to-specify-dependencies-in-aar-library)

[Can an AAR include transitive dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698160/can-an-aar-include-transitive-dependencies)

if i missed any info please comment

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the pom file in the jcenter repo to verify if the dependencies are in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question, so that might be useful for any one. Thank @Gabriele Mariotti,
I checked the pom generated, in that there is no dependencies tag available, so searched & found a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24764713/5134215) to add it.

but there they added it in `publications`, in my case one module depends on another module which is not published yet, that dependency is mention in *build.gradle* of module2 as `complie project(':module1')` and its generating the new pom which did not contains the name, description, etc., tags in publications folder.

So i added it to the previous pom fields creation area & it works for me

Here is the updated part of *gradle-mvn-push.gradle*

```
if (project.getPlugins().hasPlugin('com.android.application') ||
          project.getPlugins().hasPlugin('com.android.library')) {
    task install(type: Upload, dependsOn: assemble) {
      repositories.mavenInstaller {
        configuration = configurations.archives

        pom.groupId = GROUP
        pom.artifactId = POM_ARTIFACT_ID
        pom.version = VERSION_NAME

        pom.project {
          name POM_NAME
          packaging POM_PACKAGING
          description POM_DESCRIPTION
          url POM_URL

          scm {
            url POM_SCM_URL
            connection POM_SCM_CONNECTION
            developerConnection POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION
          }

          licenses {
            license {
              name POM_LICENCE_NAME
              url POM_LICENCE_URL
              distribution POM_LICENCE_DIST
            }
          }

          developers {
            developer {
              id pom_developer_id
              name pom_developer_name
            }
          }

        }

        //Updated part which adds dependencies in pom
        pom.withXml {
          def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

          //Iterate over the compile dependencies (we don't want the test ones), adding a <dependency> node for each
          configurations.compile.allDependencies.each {
            def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
            dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
            dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
            dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
          }
        }
      }
    }
```