# How to get one aar file dependency to another aar file?

Tags: android, android-library, aar

I am a plugin developer, my plugin have dependency of two `aar` libraries. When i am exporting as aar archive my dependent libraries not part of it.my project structure is like below mentioned

```
App  
lib1  
 --aartool   
lib2   
lib3
```

`lib1` has the dependency of `lib2`, `lib3` and `aartool` files.
`App` has `aar` dependency of `lib1`.

`Lib1` using some of the customized components from `aartool` after that `lib1` as converted to aar and used to `application`.But, whatever file we accessed from `aartool` which is not available in `application` and `throwing` `classnotfoundException`

Is there any way to implement these dependencies as `aar`?

Always i need to carry lib1 aar to application, i don't want to carry all other dependencies.

Comment: hi somebody look into this, waiting so far for answer

Comment: Down voters  please give your valuable feedback.

Comment: Please give some more details, e.g. gradle files.

Comment: are you using Gradle, or eclipse dpendency setup? The downvotes are probably for lack of details

Comment: @henry updated my details as much as i can.

Comment: "Lib1 using some of the customized components from aartool which is converted to lib1aar and used to app" -- that sentence is very unclear (it is not even valid English). Also, this is the only place in the entire question where `lib1aar` is referenced, so nobody has any idea what `lib1aar` is. To be honest, this question should have been closed as not providing a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CommonsWare updated the question which you not understood.

Comment: That did not really help much. It is clear that you think that `lib1` is somehow different than `lib2`. That difference appears to have something to do with `aartool`. But nobody knows much of anything about `lib1`, or `lib2`, or `aartool`. My only suggestion is to make sure that `lib1`, in its POM, has a dependency on `aartool`. Beyond that, you need to find a local consultant, who can sign an NDA and actually see what it is that you are talking about.

Comment: @CommonsWare it not about code issue , its all about dependency issue. Does not matter the name which i have given for the library.My major issue is while i am creating library, have dependency of some other libraries .when i am providing my library to client while dependent libraries not part of it(some other libraries).

Comment: Having libraries depend upon other libraries works "out of the box". You do it every time you depend upon `support-v13`, or `appcompat-v7`, or most of the other major Android Support libraries, which usually have a transitive dependency upon `support-v4`. Hence, somewhere, in `lib1` or `aartool`, you have a bug, perhaps in the module's `build.gradle`. But we cannot help you with that, since we cannot see those files. You need to find a local consultant, who can sign an NDA and actually see what it is that you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand it correctly, but I believe you just need to add transitive dependendcies like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698160/can-an-aar-include-transitive-dependencies) or in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795455/transitive-dependencies-not-resolved-for-aar-library-using-gradle).

Example:

```
compile ('com.foo:FOO:1.0.0@aar'){
       transitive=true
}
```

If you have circular dependencies you may encounter serious problems! I strongly recommend you to fix this.

Comment: i have tried transitive method but dependencies not part of my aar