# transitive dependencies not working for card.io and aar library using gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, card.io, transitive-dependency

Hi Im using transitive dependency for card.io  to aar library using gradle. But its throwing class not found exception from the application to card.io.
I have followed following [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698160/can-an-aar-include-transitive-dependencies) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795455/transitive-dependencies-not-resolved-for-aar-library-using-gradle) but the mentioned solutions are not working for my application. 
Application is working, when the card.io library directly importing to the working application.

any help apriciate

Comment: I think a bit more explanation is required to help you.  Please provide the relevant contents of your gradle file, the things you tried, and the error received.

Comment: Is it possible to add an aar into another aar. I want to bundle both aar libraries into one and ship it to other users. I there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, but the nested `aar` will need to be expanded, and only its contents included in the outer `aar`.  You can do this in gradle.