# Getting Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/zxing/RGBLuminanceSource; when implementing AAR

Tags: java, android, zxing, aar

I am building an AAR in which i have Zxing library implemented. When i try to use this AAR in another application it gives
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/zxing/RGBLuminanceSource;` in following  method

```
public static String decodeQRImage(Bitmap bMap) {
    String value = null;

    int[] intArray = new int[bMap.getWidth() * bMap.getHeight()];
    bMap.getPixels(intArray, 0, bMap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight());
    LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(), intArray);
    BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

    Reader reader = new QRCodeReader();
    try {
        Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);
        value = result.getText();
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        value = e.getMessage();
    } catch (ChecksumException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        value = e.getMessage();
    } catch (FormatException e) {
        value = e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return value;
}
```

and when i use above method directly in application without implementing it in AAR it runs perfectly

Following are the dependencies used in AAR

```
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.kaopiz:kprogresshud:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0'
    implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.scottyab:rootbeer-lib:0.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation "androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0"

    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.6.3'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
```

and following are the dependencies used in application

```
    implementation project(":ziplibrary-debug")
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.1'
```

Comment: Show the list of your dependencies of AAR and of the application you build.

Comment: I have used Zxing dependency in AAR but not in application.
Is that compulsory to add Zxing dependency also in application? 
if yes then i will have to add all other dependencies in application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AAR is built with your code only. No dependencies end up in AAR by default. Here is an option on [how to include dependencies into AAR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33539941/7210237).

Also, it may be helpful to know about transitive dependencies: [Transitive dependencies not resolved for aar library using gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25730092/7210237)

#### Update

To fix the issue with `META-INF` files you can use Gradle `packagingOptions`. Inside of your `build.gradle` file find `android` block and insert the following:

```
android {
    ...

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/retrofit.kotlin_module'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I added all dependencies using task and it worked. But if someone uses my AAR and adds same dependency in his application as i added in my AAR then build failed with this message- ```More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/retrofit.kotlin_module'```