# Use android library without re-including all its dependencies

Tags: java, android, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin, libraries

TL; DR: When using a library in an AndroidProject, why must I include all library's dependencies ?

Long story:
Let's say I have a simple Android Library Project that contains a module named `LibModule`.
Let's say this library `LibModule` depends on another library, defined in `LibModule/build.gradle` like this :

```
dependencies {
    // example :
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0-beta1' 
}
```

I'm able to generate the library of this module, `LibModule.aar`.

Now I want to use classes from the library `LibModule` in a new Android Project called `MyApp`.
I copy this `LibModule.aar` into `MyApp/app/libs/`. 
Then in `MyApp/app/build.gradle`, I add this :

```
dependencies {  
        compile(name:'LibModule', ext:'aar')  
}
```

I'm now able to uses classes from `LibModule` in MyApp's Activities. It compiles great. No errors.
When I launch MyApp/app, at runtime, I get this stacktrace when using `LibModule`'s classes :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/jivesoftware/smack/tcp/XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration;
(...Stacktrace...)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/MyApp/app/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
(...)
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration
(...)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

`XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration` comes from `org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0-beta1`, a dependency of `LibModule`.
It's really weird !
I found a solution to this : adding `org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0-beta1` dependency in `MyApp/app`'s `build.gradle`, but I guess this is not the right way to manage this error.

I thought `org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0-beta1` was "packed" in LibModule.aar, but it seems not...

I would like to know if there is something I'm doing badly, because this workaround looks realy dirty to me!

EDIT: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795455/transitive-dependencies-not-resolved-for-aar-library-using-gradle%20this) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795455/transitive-dependencies-not-resolved-for-aar-library-using-gradle) , but none of the answer resolved the problem....

Comment: Same issue here with another library (okHttp). Seems that the transitive=true parameter only work with maven library, and not with local .aar file.