# what's the meaning of @aar with transitive = true

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

i use [crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install) only as an example.

what's is the difference from

```
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') { transitive = true; }
```

and

```
    compile 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8'
```

Comment: i guess it is answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731014/what-does-transitive-true-in-gradle-exactly-do-w-r-t-crashlytics

Comment: i read that but "Existing module descriptors are ignored" is not clear. in the case of crashlytics which module descriptors will be ignored?

Comment: It means that you want to download only the aar artifact, and no dependencies.

Comment: no with "transitive = true" you download dependency

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use the `...@artifacttype` notation in a Gradle dependency it means "only get me this artifact and no transitive dependencies". By additionally setting `transitive = true`, you are fetching the transitive dependencies despite that fact.

The first version gets the `aar` with dependencies and as far as I remember the second always gets the `jar` if one is present and else nothing but the dependencies. Add `configurations.compile.each { println it }` to output the actual files in the configuration and you should see the difference.

In the case of `crashlytics` there is no difference:

```
compile 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8'
/home/xan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.crashlytics.sdk.android/crashlytics/2.6.8/2f667ae0609d82045cbe602d38df3fbf2c9528dd/crashlytics-2.6.8.aar
/home/xan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.crashlytics.sdk.android/beta/1.2.5/f73d30657bb44ecb79d434a4ae3fb7d887371d84/beta-1.2.5.aar
/home/xan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.fabric.sdk.android/fabric/1.3.17/85fc9aae9009f6fb2beaf23fa0ce1ae13f124413/fabric-1.3.17.aar
/home/xan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.crashlytics.sdk.android/crashlytics-core/2.3.17/f3bed4c297be8d30dc5aa7f18b06dff75435bde4/crashlytics-core-2.3.17.aar
/home/xan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.crashlytics.sdk.android/answers/1.3.13/83dc1dd439c7da04ce9705f18037fe7551ae06bc/answers-1.3.13.aar

compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') { transitive = true; }
/home/xan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.crashlytics.sdk.android/crashlytics/2.6.8/2f667ae0609d82045cbe602d38df3fbf2c9528dd/crashlytics-2.6.8.aar
/home/xan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.crashlytics.sdk.android/beta/1.2.5/f73d30657bb44ecb79d434a4ae3fb7d887371d84/beta-1.2.5.aar
/home/xan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.fabric.sdk.android/fabric/1.3.17/85fc9aae9009f6fb2beaf23fa0ce1ae13f124413/fabric-1.3.17.aar
/home/xan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.crashlytics.sdk.android/crashlytics-core/2.3.17/f3bed4c297be8d30dc5aa7f18b06dff75435bde4/crashlytics-core-2.3.17.aar
/home/xan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.crashlytics.sdk.android/answers/1.3.13/83dc1dd439c7da04ce9705f18037fe7551ae06bc/answers-1.3.13.aar
```

Comment: i will check, where i need to put gradle line?

Comment: Just put it in the end of the build script, that should be good enough and then will execute always, no matter what task you call. Just do `gradlew help` after you added the line.

Comment: Is there a way to see which artifacts is a library in jcenter or mavencentral?

Comment: I don't unterstand your question

Comment: each library can have multiple artifact, What is the easiest way to know what they are?

Comment: Go to the web page of the repository and look at what's there