# Android - Gradle dependencies of Library Modules

Tags: android, gradle

In Android Studio, I've created an Android Library Module. Said module has its own Gradle file, and I intend to make it as independent from the app that will be using it as possible - that means that the user doesn't have to copy the Library Module's Gradle dependencies into the app module's Gradle dependencies block.

How do I go about doing it? Do I have to search for the `.jar` files of said dependencies and add them to the Library Module instead of the ordinary `compile '<libpackage>:<libname>:<libversion>'` lines in Gradle?

Answer (score 0):

You can export this library into aar file and compile this file as library, it will download all inside library dependencies

Export library to AAR here: [Create aar file in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309950/create-aar-file-in-android-studio?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: I've done this, and like I said, I still had to copy the dependencies block in its Gradle file into the main app's Gradle file. I need a method that eliminates the need to do that.

Comment: Could you try with setting "transitive = true" in the AAR library dependencies.
More detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731014/what-does-transitive-true-in-gradle-exactly-do-w-r-t-crashlytics?answertab=votes#tab-top