# Android Creating Library doesn't work after being import

Tags: android, android-library

i have made a library in android

using volley, Gson and Glide.

and created a .aar file

when trying to import in other project(which contains Gson or Volley or Glide) 
it doesn't work.. it gives multidex error..

i dont want this error to come..

why it doesn't work and whats the work around to make my library...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31753839/1827254

Comment: let me try then i will tell you