# Duplicate Classes : javax.activation... when Building Project with Gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm getting a failed build when running the project on my phone via USB after adding the following implementation on my build.gradle file :

```
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.1'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.10.1'
```

The build is successful without running on device though.
Below are the duplicated files on the Build output :

```
    Duplicate class javax.activation.ActivationDataFlavor found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.CommandInfo found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.CommandMap found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.CommandObject found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.DataContentHandler found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.DataContentHandlerFactory found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.DataHandler found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.DataHandler$1 found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.DataHandlerDataSource found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.DataSource found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.DataSourceDataContentHandler found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.FileDataSource found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.FileTypeMap found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.MimeType found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.MimeTypeParameterList found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.MimeTypeParseException found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.SecuritySupport found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.SecuritySupport$1 found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.SecuritySupport$2 found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.SecuritySupport$3 found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.SecuritySupport$4 found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.SecuritySupport$5 found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.URLDataSource found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException found in modules jetified-activation (activation.jar) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was happening because of Safe Nav Args Dependency. So, try removing dependencies and check which one is causing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's happening because you are using two libs that use the same dependencies, try to add transitive = true to Jackson, as far as it seems like you are using one called jakarta that using javax.activation.

What does transtitive do? check this post.

[What does transitive = true in Gradle exactly do (w.r.t. crashlytics)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731014/what-does-transitive-true-in-gradle-exactly-do-w-r-t-crashlytics)

Comment: Still  the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the problem by commenting out id ("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34780231)