# Adding @jar or @aar to Gradle Dependency Breaks Automatic Dependency Resolution

Tags: java, android, gradle, pom.xml

Adding this to my build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
```

Leads to gradle resolving the dependencies for this lib automatically. (I assume this is based on the pom file):

```
$ gradle -q dependencies

_debugCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
\--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0
     +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0
     |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0
     +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.2.0
     |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0
     |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 (*)
     +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.2.0
     |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0
     |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 (*)
     +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.2.0
     |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0
     |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 (*)
     \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:25.2.0
          +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 (*)
          +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.2.0 (*)
          +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.2.0 (*)
          \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.2.0 (*)
```

When I explicitly require the jar or the aar version of that package in build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0@aar' // or @jar
```

it breaks the dependency resolution:

```
$ gradle -q dependencies

_debugCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
\--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0
```

Question: Is this a bug in gradle, or how do I make gradle resolve the dependencies also when using @aar and @jar notation?

Comment: I think this answer < http://stackoverflow.com/a/30071402/3390459 > more or less addresses your question.

Comment: Woop Woop! That fixes, it! If you want to create an anwer, feel free, so I can select it ;)
Otherwise here is what worked for me `compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0@aar') {
        transitive=true
    }`