# Gradle - Android - 2 Libraries dependency conflict

Tags: android, gradle

I have 2 libs that I know that has dependency to different versions of the 3rd one. I get a compile error of `Duplicate class`.

[image]

Comment: Not sure if you've seen: [Transitive dependencies not resolved for aar library using gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22795455/295004) but you should provide detail about what you've tried/how your project build is structured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
implementation(Lib A){
   exclude module : 'lib c' 
}
```

Comment: this is what i did and it works implementation('com.amplifyframework:aws-storage-s3:1.35.4') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.play', module: 'core'
    }