# Is isReleaseBuild() part of the Android Gradle DSL?

Tags: android, gradle

I followed instructions similar to these:

[Android Library Gradle release JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307341/android-library-gradle-release-jar)

However, I get the following error:

> Could not find method isReleaseBuild() for arguments [] on project ':myProject'.

None of the examples I saw on Maven integration define this function, so I assumed it was built-in. However, I get this error  with Gradle 1.12 and 2.1, and Android plugin 0.12.+ and 0.13.+

If it's not a built-in function, what is the best practice for defining it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is user defined, but seems to permeate examples because a lot of Gradle examples are copied.

This is the way I ended up defining it, so that I could pass in `-PMAVEN_RELEASE_BUILD` on the command line to turn on release builds.

```
def isReleaseBuild() {
    return hasProperty("MAVEN_RELEASE_BUILD") && MAVEN_RELEASE_BUILD == "true";
}
```

Some people also like to define as version names ending in `-SNAPSHOT`. I do not prefer to do this, because I want to be able to choose whether to build a release or debug build without checking in a change to gradle.properties.

```
def isReleaseBuild() {
    return !VERSION_NAME.contains("SNAPSHOT");
}
```