# Can Android Studio library contain resources

Tags: android

I know there was an issue in the past with Eclipse ADT where you could not compile a library project to a JAR if it contained resources.

Is it possible to do this with Android Studio and compile to an AAR file? I would also like to convert the AAR file to JAR and need to know if this will cause issue.

Thanks

Comment: AAR contains a jar inside

Answer (score 0):

With the Android Gradle Plugin, you can package a library as aar or, if your library doesn't contain Android resources, as a jar [using this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307341/android-library-gradle-release-jar).