# Use provided/compileOnly dependency with Android libraries

Tags: java, android, gradle, jar

For a project, I have this type of structure :

`--- app => my Android application
 |
 \- lib => my Android library`

The application use methods from the lib, but I want a build without embedding classes from the lib (since they are also available in a custom AOSP build), which could be done with provided/compileOnly directive for dependencies. The problem is that this directive doesn't work with aar librairies generated by the Android plugin, only with jars.

I found a way to build also jar files by using the custom makeJar task found here :
[Build library jar with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29922268/build-library-jar-with-gradle)

Then in the build.gradle for the application, I can add a dependency like this :

`dependencies {
    compileOnly fileTree(dir: '../lib/build/outputs/jar', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
}`

This works fine, but only if the jar has already been generated by a previous build, which means I have to launch `./gradlew build` two time to make it work.

I suppose the problem is that unlike regular dependencies (ie `compileOnly project(':lib')`), the fileTree dependency is evaluated without requesting a build of the sub project and on the first build, no jar file is added to the classpath.

I tried things like `preBuild.dependsOn(':lib:makeJar')` but without success because it's executed after evaluation.

I can't switch lib to Java plugin because it's Android specific code and I need to build aar for other projects, so is there a better way to use the compileOnly directive with this module ? Or maybe a way to force the lib to be built before the app build.gradle is evaluated ?

Answer (score -3):

add this on your build.gradle(app)

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

or directly compile your jar file as following

```
compile files('libs/your_filename_in_libs_folder.jar')
```

Comment: The libs folder must be in app folder. If it doesn't exist their create it

Comment: Not really what I want, I keep the lib as a module to recompile it everytime. This way I have to copy the jar each time it changes.

Comment: if you keep it as a module, do this
compile project(path: ':lib')

Comment: Using "compile" (or "implement" since Android Gradle Plugin 3) will embed classes from the lib into the apk, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: instead of **compile**, you can use **implementation**

Comment: **implementation** is just the new syntax since Android Gradle Plugin 3, it does exactly the same as **compile**