# How to create single jar with FatJar (Gradle)

Tags: java, gradle, jar

I want to generate a single Jar with multiple modules and dependencies. I installed `FatJar Plugin` but I got the below error:

[image]

**My Code:**

[image]

**Trying shadowJar**

> Error:(61, 0) Could not find method shadowJar() for arguments
>   [build_eqgfg4x39smehqcteaccdy4k6$_run_closure4@780b32c6] on project
>   ':SDKFramework' of type org.gradle.api.Project. Open File

**My build.gradle (module)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'groovyx.grooid.groovy-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:gradle-groovy-android-plugin:0.3.10'
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.3'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile project(':framework2')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

shadowJar {

}
```

Comment: 1. "is this the crusty crab?"
2. your classpath is in the wrong build.gradle
3. your task too

Comment: Ok. Now I have the code in my module build.gradle but the error remains

Comment: Please post your code and error as text, instead of images.

Comment: try this: https://gist.github.com/kesco/77132337ab0d8dc81016

Comment: Apply the shadow plugin in the first statement in the build.gradle

Comment: @yonisha sorry, same error :( I do not want to bother you anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found **solution:**

```
task createJar(type: Jar) {
    from {
        List<File> allFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        configurations.compile.collect {
            for (File f : zipTree(it).getFiles()) {
                if (f.getName().equals("classes.jar")) {
                    allFiles.addAll(zipTree(f).getAt("asFileTrees").get(0).getDir())
                }
            }
        }
        allFiles.add(new File('build/intermediates/classes/release'))
        allFiles // To return the result inside a lambda
    }
    archiveName('MySDK.jar')
}
```

**This code** generate a single jar with all classes.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple solution is to use the [shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow).
Using the plugin is very straightforward:

1. Declare the plugin as the first statement in your build.grade:

> plugins {
>   id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version
>   "1.2.3"
>  }

2. Apply either **java** or **groovy** plugin.

> apply plugin: 'java'

or

> apply plugin: 'groovy'

3. Refresh the project and run the newly 'shadowJar' task.

This plugin also enable you to exclude dependencies, redirect (rename) packages' names and much more.

Comment: If I use: shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()
}

Give me next error: the proyect may be using a version of the Android Gradle Plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0)

Comment: what is mergeServiceFiles function?

Comment: It´s a shadow function for test. Gradle don´t recognize shadowJar methods but plugin was installed correctly

Comment: Do you have java plugin or groovy plugin enabled? it is required. updated my answer

Comment: Updated my question too

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following line to your **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

Because, gradle don't have "Jar" task by default. You can read about that, here 
https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html

If you using android, then add here:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
```

or

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Comment: I tried. The 'java' plugin has been applied, but is not compatible with de android plugins

Comment: just add clear android plugin: apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

Comment: apply plugin: 'android' is deprecated and you cannot combine apply plugin: 'com.android.library' with apply plugin: 'java'

Comment: Of cause, use just apply plugin: 'com.android.library'. Okay, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307341/android-library-gradle-release-jar